# Shortcut for commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, macros

I do

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
...some commutative diagram...
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

dozens of times a day. Is there a way to make a shortcut, like, for example,

```
\diagram{
...some commutative diagram...
}
```

?

Comment: you could do something like `\newcommand\diagram[1]{\begin{center}\begin{tikzcd}#1\end{tikzcd}\end{center}` but hiding environment syntax usually isn't a win, it makes spotting the end harder (just a trailing `}`)  and in most editors adding the environments should only be a few keystrokes, possibly less than typing `\diagram`

Comment: This is a problem related to your TeX editor, in my opinion: *it* should have a shortcut to type this code.

Comment: Instead of `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` you should use `\[...\]`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not at all complicated. But you'll regret doing so as soon as you realize you need to use `\&` as column separator (not a big deal, perhaps) and you lose the possibility of numbering the diagram with the standard methods.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\newcommand{\diagram}[2][]{%
  \begin{equation*}% better than center
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,#1]
  #2
  \end{tikzcd}
  \end{equation*}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\diagram{
  A \arrow[r,"f"] \arrow[d,"\alpha"] \& B \arrow[d,"\beta"] \\
  C \arrow[r,"g"] \& D
}
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[r,"f"] \arrow[d,"\alpha"] & B \arrow[d,"\beta"] \\
  C \arrow[r,"g"] & D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Can you see a real improvement in the former input with respect to the latter?

[image]

You can pass options to diagram like so

```
\diagram[column sep=4em]{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Why is "equation" better than "center"? Also, since this solution seems non-standard and not regarded as a very good one, do you have a better suggestion for speeding up by writing?

Comment: @Spenser Because `equation*` will take care not to detach the diagram from the previous text (not guaranteed with `center`). Use a good text editor, or learn fast typing: using an inflexible macro is not the solution.

Comment: Thanks! What would a good text editor do? I use TexShop.

Comment: @Spenser You can define shortcuts. Personally I use very few of them, but I'm quite fast at typing.